# Why Wildfly26 returns an error when deploying a war?

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-26

I'm trying to upgrade my application's wildfly version from 18.0.1 to 26.1.3 but I got an error. It works well in version 18.0.1:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 94) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."TmgRestApi.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."TmgRestApi.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name is empty
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.3.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name is empty
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:257)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.3.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.3.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name is empty
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:391)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.registerProvider(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:735)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.registration(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:459)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.startInternal(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.start(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:121)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.7.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextInitialized(ResteasyBootstrap.java:29)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.3.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.3.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.3.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.1.3.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
    ... 10 more

13:01:10,560 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "TmgRestApi.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"TmgRestApi.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name is empty
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name is empty
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name is empty"}}
13:01:10,609 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "TmgAngular.war" (runtime-name : "TmgAngular.war")
13:01:10,610 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "TmgRestApi.war" (runtime-name : "TmgRestApi.war")
13:01:10,612 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."TmgRestApi.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name is empty
```

I tried to find online but suggestions are not usefull for my case.

Comment: Your web.xml or servlet declaration is 'wrong':  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name is empty

Comment: Yes, if you've got a `web.xml` file in your deployment it would be helpful if you posted it here.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I found the solution by changing web.xml